# Any significant reason to avoid `as IQueryable`?

Tags: c#, casting, iqueryable

I have a library of model-to-viewmodel mapping extension methods. Supporting them is a base class with a few common methods, including `Transform`, below:

```
internal abstract class TransformBase<TOriginal, TConverted>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TOriginal, TConverted>> Expression { get; }

    public IQueryable<TConverted> Transform(IEnumerable<TOriginal> value)
    {
        var queryable = value as IQueryable<TOriginal> ?? value.AsQueryable();
        return queryable.Select(Expression);
    }
```

My question: is there any significant reason, besides a negligible performance hit, that I should avoid the `as IQueryable` cast above? For example, I could instead do the following:

```
internal abstract class TransformBase<TOriginal, TConverted>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TOriginal, TConverted>> Expression { get; }

    public IQueryable<TConverted> Transform(IQueryable<TOriginal> value)
    {
        return value.Select(Expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TConverted> Transform(IEnumerable<TOriginal> value)
    {
        return value.AsQueryable().Select(Expression);
    }
```

... but I would prefer not to have to write the overloads in every one of my dependent classes. EDIT: To clarify, here is an example of what I'm seeking to avoid:

```
public static class TransformCompany
{
    private static readonly TransformBase<Organization, CompanyHeader> header = new TransformPrecompiled<Organization, CompanyHeader>(
    company => new CompanyHeader
    {
        Name = company.Name,
    });

    public static IQueryable<CompanyHeader> AsHeaders(this IQueryable<Organization> companies)
    {
        return header.Transform(companies);
    }

    // Note I have to include this capability in each of my dependent classes
    // Worse is the possibility that someone may accidentally implement
    // only IEnumerable for a future model transformation,
    // causing a hidden data performance problem
    public static IQueryable<CompanyHeader> AsHeaders(this IEnumerable<Organization> companies)
    {
        return header.Transform(companies);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last sentence. Both sets of code look the same to me, except the second one is much more readable.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Note that understanding the clarification isn't strictly necessary to answer my question. I don't mean that in a passive-aggressive manner, I'm just trying to avoid derailing the question by including this new information.

Comment: @Rhumborl: re:difference, the first uses reflection and cast, while the second does not. There may also be side-effects I've overlooked, which is why I've asked the question.

Comment: Could you clarify your doubts more? Is this a performance critical code? I don't see any obvious reasons the cast is bad, nor is the extension method alone. You are asking for an advice but it is difficult to give one without broader context.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: There are typically 1-3 calls to model transformations for every WebAPI request made. That means A) it's not totally irrelevant, since it is in front of nearly every web request, but B) it's not really "performance critical", since an activity like reflection is pretty minor compared to a database-bound network client request.

Comment: @WiktorZychla : Sorry, re: my doubts, I fear that I've overlooked something important. Like, it's actually a bigger performance hit than one call to reflection. Or, perhaps this code might cause IQueryable to be treated as IEnumerable under some conditions, or cause some funky expression parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you do not need separate extensions for `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` as `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, and you also do not need to the cast.

Looking at [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,080010ec4b6beced), `AsQueryable()` actually does this check for you:

```
public static IQueryable<TElement> AsQueryable<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (source is IQueryable<TElement>)
        return (IQueryable<TElement>)source;
    return new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(source);
}
```

Therefore the following should work for you with no performance hit:

```
internal abstract class TransformBase<TOriginal, TConverted>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TOriginal, TConverted>> Expression { get; }

    public IQueryable<TConverted> Transform(IEnumerable<TOriginal> value)
    {
        return value.AsQueryable().Select(Expression);
    }
}


public static class TransformCompany
{
    public static IQueryable<CompanyHeader> AsHeaders(this IEnumerable<Organization> companies)
    {
        return header.Transform(companies);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Queryable.AsQueryable Method (IEnumerable)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the type of source implements IQueryable,
>   AsQueryable(IEnumerable) returns it directly. Otherwise, it returns an
>   IQueryable that executes queries by calling the equivalent query
>   operator methods in Enumerable instead of those in Queryable.

Instead of casting you simplify your `Transform` method to

```
return value.AsQueryable().Select(Expression);
```

Comment: Thank you. I selected @Rhumborl's answer since he also gave his opinion on my main question, that I do not need separate method signatures for any reason.